# LEFT JOIN and finding the missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to find some help with working out this function.  I am trying to list all the `SERIAL_NUMBER` items in the `oL` table that do NOT exist in the `rL` table, that contain a particular value.

Below is the code I came up with but haven't gotten any further.  No matter how I seem to write it, I always produce all of the `SERIAL_NUMBER` items that exist or nothing at all.

```
DECLARE @val int
SET @val = 43770

SELECT oL.SERIAL_NUMBER 
FROM 
    ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_ORDER_OPTICS AS oL 
    LEFT JOIN ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS AS rL 
        ON oL.SERIAL_NUMBER != rL.SERIAL_NUMBER
WHERE oL.SO_LINE_NUMBER = @val;
```

What am I doing wrong here?  This code produces all of the results where the `oL.SO_LINE_NUMBER = @val`.  I need that - minus the serial numbers that already exist in the `rL` table.

I've also tried adding

```
WHERE rl.SERIAL_NUMBER IS NULL
```

but that produces nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addition on Vladirmir answer, you just mess with the joining condition and filtering condition.

However you need to take care of the multiplier effect of join if the value duplicate in rows. If you just want to check the existence, you can use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT oL.SERIAL_NUMBER 
FROM ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_ORDER_OPTICS oL 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS rL 
        WHERE oL.SERIAL_NUMBER = rL.SERIAL_NUMBER)
    AND oL.SO_LINE_NUMBER = @val
```

Comment: Also producing ALL results with the given @val.

Comment: @Addohm Then you should post the sample data for checking

Comment: Hmm, how to post multiple table data ><

Comment: @Addohm I just think your 2 table's `SERIAL_NUMBER` is not equal if the value is different / your database collation is case sensitive / different data type on those table.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Z_oCkQ0NlxAER_1HBkK-Bg7t2aiJNLTKU0wcsLUQi8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The data is identical and the data types are exactly the same, I've checked those things already.  SERIAL_NUMBER(PK, varchar(50), not null)

Comment: use this : select ol.SERIAL_NUMBER from aof_order_optics ol where ol.SERIAL_NUMBER not in(select rl.SERIAL_NUMBER from aof_optic_results rl) and ol.SO_LINE_NUMBER=@val;

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks almost correct.

You should join on `oL.SERIAL_NUMBER = rL.SERIAL_NUMBER` (not `!=`) and then leave only those rows that have `rL.SERIAL_NUMBER IS NULL`. This filter means that there are no rows in `rL` with such `SERIAL_NUMBER`.

```
DECLARE @val int;
SET @val = 43770;

SELECT 
    oL.SERIAL_NUMBER 
FROM 
    ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_ORDER_OPTICS AS oL 
    LEFT JOIN ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS AS rL
        ON oL.SERIAL_NUMBER = rL.SERIAL_NUMBER
WHERE 
    oL.SO_LINE_NUMBER = @val
    AND rL.SERIAL_NUMBER IS NULL
;
```

Comment: I've done code very similar to this.  I've also tried copying your code.  It produces all 5 items that contain that SO_LINE_NUMBER.  It is NOT filtering out the ones that already exist in the rL table.

Comment: The query in the answer should return serial numbers that don't exist in `rL`.  I'd recommend to create two simple test tables instead of your real tables with the minimum number of relevant columns. Add few rows with some sample data to them and see how the queries work.

Comment: Maybe your `rL` table indeed doesn't have any serial numbers that you see in the result. It is easy to verify: `SELECT * FROM rL WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER = <the number from your result>`

Comment: Interesting!  I copied one of the results of the query, and added the above when querying the other table and nothing shows.  Fantom spaces?

Comment: Obviously, the values **are** different, even though they may **look** the same in SSMS grid. Most likely there is a carriage return or some other non-printable character somewhere. One way to check is to show their binary values and see if they match: `CAST(SERIAL_NUMBER as varbinary(8000))`

Comment: I went through and deleted all the test data, then recreated it paying extra attention to what excel was doing.  The code works.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: As an aside, how do I set @val to a value returned by a query?  Something like:  `SET @val = (SELECT lQ.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER
 FROM ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_ORDER_QUEUE AS oQ
 LEFT JOIN ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE AS lQ
 ON oQ.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = lQ.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER)`

Comment: `SET` will work, if the query returns one row. Or `SELECT @val = column FROM tbl`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a subquery like this:

```
DECLARE @val int;
SET @val = 43770;

SELECT 
    oL.SERIAL_NUMBER 
FROM 
    ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_ORDER_OPTICS AS oL 
WHERE 
    oL.SO_LINE_NUMBER = @val
    AND oL.SERIAL_NUMBER NOT IN (
      SELECT rL.SERIAL_NUMBER
      FROM ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT.dbo.AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS AS rL
    )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:
 `select ol.SERIAL_NUMBER from aof_order_optics ol where ol.SERIAL_NUMBER not in(select rl.SERIAL_NUMBER from aof_optic_results rl) and ol.SO_LINE_NUMBER=@val;`